# How to get buttons to show over maps activity

Tags: android, android-layout

I have tried like 5 different ways to try and get buttons to show over a maps activity, but no matter what I try I can't seem to get them to show up, anybody know what I am doing wrong? This pertains to android studio

Here is code from activity_maps.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/currentloca"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:backgroundTint="#818181"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:visibility="visible">

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="553dp"
    tools:context=".MapsActivity" />

<androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

<Button
        android:id="@+id/zoomin"
        android:layout_width="205dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="onZoom"
        android:text="Zoom In" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/zoomout"
        android:layout_width="205dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="onZoom"
        android:text="Zoom Out" />


</androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: you are using linear layout in map fragment that's why it doesn't work. i think you want RelativeLayout instead because i assume you want button designed ON the top of map

Comment: I think you should test your layout with some *mock* fragment other than the SupportMapFragment.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `FrameLayout` or its sort instead of `LinearLayout`. Below is just showing a structure for an explanation:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <fragment
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
    
        <Button />
        <Button />
    
    </LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

`LinearLayout` lays its child views on a horizontal or vertical line. While `FrameLayout` over-lays its children.

About your actual code, at first, replace (overwrite) the surrounding (outer most) `LinearLayout`:

```
<LinearLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/currentloca"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:backgroundTint="#818181"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:visibility="visible">

(...)

</LinearLayout>
```

with `FrameLayout`:

```
<FrameLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/currentloca"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:backgroundTint="#818181"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:visibility="visible">

(...)

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: @Newtz Try to change the surrounding LinearLayout to FrameLayout.

Comment: I can't post the new changed code on here due to comment characters max

Comment: I have edited the original post to what I have now. I am not sure If I am understanding you correctly with what you are saying. Please clarify if this is what you meant, either way though I am given an error when attempting to build this.

Comment: @Newtz your code modification was not what I intended. I have updated my post.

Comment: I have tried adjusting it to be a FrameLayout and still get the exact same result, the map but with no shown buttons. (p.s. sorry for the late response I work super long shifts)

Comment: I am not totally sure why It is not working, I haven't had any sort of trouble with buttons or overlays in the past, I only have a problem when it comes to this map activity.

Comment: I have tried every solution and still dont get it to work

Answer (score 0):

Remove the first parent `LinearLayout` from your code.
Updated code should look like this.

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/currentloca"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:backgroundTint="#818181"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:visibility="visible">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="555dp">

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/map"
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="553dp"
            tools:context=".MapsActivity" />

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/zoomin"
                android:layout_width="205dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:onClick="onZoom"
                android:text="Zoom In" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/zoomout"
                android:layout_width="205dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:onClick="onZoom"
                android:text="Zoom Out" />


        </androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>
    </FrameLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

If you want your Views to potentially overlap, use a `FrameLayout`. If you want them displayed linearly, use a `LinearLayout`

Comment: I am updating my code on the original post. It still does not work @nitish chaudhary

Comment: @Newtz , I believe you don't want to show maps on full screen as maps fragment as fixed height of 555dp. If you want maps to show on full screen , replace height of maps with match_parent. But if that's what your requirement , I have update the code to adjust buttons on bottom of  the map. In this case bottom of screen will be white(empty) for larger devices.

Comment: I have tried different devices and yet nothing changes. I have never had this many problems

Comment: Can you attach the screenshot in the query as what exactly is happening and what's required in UI for better understanding.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in comment, I think your need is a relative layout. Here is a example.

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">


       <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="553dp"
        tools:context=".MapsActivity" />

         <LinearLayout
             android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
             android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
             android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content">

               <Button />
               <Button />

         </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

This way the buttons will appears in the top of the map fragment.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you should use ConstriantLayout and LinearLayout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".Activities.Maps">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        map:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        map:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        map:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/zoomin"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="onZoom"
            android:text="Zoom In" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/zoomout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="onZoom"
            android:text="Zoom Out" />


    </LinearLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: I have tried this, and under my tools:context is gives me a red error. Also upon running the code it does not work either. In fact none of the comments have worked or even changed the app itsself. It shows it in the design portion but on the actual app it doesnt show the buttons above or any sort of changes at all